# Tableview search bar not showing any data and giving some error some times when i run

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using swift 2.0 . And i have added search bar to table view. i have run 2 times, its worked well. But now in my code its showing error :

`Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(@noescape (Element) throws -> Bool)'`

When i try to run also not able to search my table view data ,

Here is my full code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate

{

    var Table:NSArray = []

  @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    var searchActive : Bool = false
     var filtered:[String] = []


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!   // UITable view declaration

    @IBOutlet weak var Resultcount: UILabel!     // count label

    let cellSpacingHeight: CGFloat = 5  // cell spacing from each cell in table view




    var filteredTableData = [String]()
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {


        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

       CallWebService() // call the json method


        // nib for custom cell (table view)
        let nib = UINib(nibName:"customCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


        searchBar.delegate = self

    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = true;
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
    }

    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filtered = Table.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
            let tmp: NSString = text as! NSString
            let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
            return range.location != NSNotFound
        })
        if(filtered.count == 0){
            searchActive = false;
        } else {
            searchActive = true;
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }



    // every time app quit and run, switch will be in off state
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(true)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "PremiumUser")

    }





    func CallWebService()
    {
        let UrlApi = "url"
        let Url = NSURL(string: UrlApi)
        let Session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let Work = Session.dataTaskWithURL(Url!, completionHandler: { dataTask, response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print(error)
            }
            var datos:NSData = NSData(data: dataTask!)

            do {


                let JsonWithDatos:AnyObject! = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(datos, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray


                self.Table = JsonWithDatos as! NSArray


                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {



                    if (self.Table.count>0)
                    {
                        self.Resultcount.text = "\(self.Table.count) Results"
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }


                }
            }catch{
                print("Some error occured")
            }


        })

        Work.resume()
    }




    // number of sections
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 1
    }
    // number of rows
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {



        if(searchActive) {
            return filtered.count
        }
       return self.Table.count
    }







        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        let cell:customCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! customCell 
            if(searchActive){
               cell.vendorName.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
            } else {
                cell.vendorName.text = Table[indexPath.row] as! String;
            }

            let item = self.Table[indexPath.row] as! [String : String]
             cell.vendorName.text = item["name"]
            cell.vendorAddress.text = item["address"]


        return cell 
    }




}
```

i am getting error in this method `func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {` in this line `filtered = Table.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
            let tmp: NSString = text as! NSString
            let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
            return range.location != NSNotFound
        })`

Why its work one time , that time also not able to do search in my table view. Now I am suddenly getting this error.

Comment: your code's wired indentation and empty lines don't encourage to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have implemented search controller in table view 
i give you my function that filter the searched data and make an array with matching strings

```
func filterDestinations(searchString: String){
    self.filteredDestinations.removeAll()
    if(self.defaultarray.count > 0){
        for obj in self.sortedDest{
            if(obj.name!.rangeOfString(searchString, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil){
                self.filteredDestinations.append(obj)
            }
        }
    }    
}// ends filterDestinations
```

after that you just reload your table view and in function cellforrowatindex you check that if search controller is active than you give data from your filltered array otherwise use your default array.
also you have to set numberofrows by check search controller is active or not.
if its active then return the filltered array count otherwise return your default array count so your app wont crash .

Comment: now i need to add your func method and i need to reload my table view in cell row at index path??...

Comment: Sorry for so late 
No brother
you have to reload your table view in Search Controller function after calling this function.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the closure parameter and return value type. Also `rangeOfString` returns `nil` if the string was not found. And better to cast to Swift `String` not `NSString`. You are trying to assign `NSArray` (basically `[AnyObject]` to `[String]`. You have to do some mapping.

```
filtered = table.filter {
    let tmp = $0 as! String
    let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch)
    return range != nil
}.map { $0 as! String }
```

Comment: i did same error ` Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(@noescape (Element) throws -> Bool)'

Comment: instead of this code ` filtered = Table.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
            let tmp: NSString = text as! NSString
            let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
            return range.location != NSNotFound
        })`   i replace you code

Comment: When i replace also in that `.filer` i am getting this error

Comment: The reason is that as you are using NSArray the return type is also NSArray when you are expecting [String].

Comment: now i am getting crash `Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x1091d0d38) to 'NSString' (0x10883bb20).`    at `cell row at index path ` at this line ` cell.vendorName.text = Table[indexPath.row] as! String;`

Comment: every time i am getting different different crash. really struck alot

Comment: You are casting a String to [String : String]. Does Table have Strings or dictionaries of Strings?

Comment: I don't understand why you even use NSArray in Swift code. That's an untyped Objective-C class. Swift uses strong typing just to prevent the kind of errors you have done.

Comment: actually i am getting json value and displaying in table view and also i need to search and filter them with like decending to ascending order. For that i am confused about this dic or string?

Comment: How can i rewrite code to avoid this error or my mistakes.

Comment: You should not use the json structures directly in ui code. Just convert it first to a typed data model.

Comment: That i have to do in my web service call know under my ` CallWebService()`. Really i am struck for long time

Comment: i am new to handle ios swift 2.0. I thought i have converted my json to array.But i din't??. If possible can you help me out to solve this conversion in my web service call??